# Cast from shared pointer to shared pointer to const

Tags: c++, constants, return-value, shared-ptr, reference-binding

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A( )
        : m_i( new int )
    { }

    std::shared_ptr< const int >&
    get( )
    {
        return m_i; // <-- invalid initialization of reference of type
                    //     'std::shared_ptr<const int>&' from 
                    //     expression of type 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr< int > m_i;
};


int main( )
{
    A a;
    auto& i = a.get( );

    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How is it possible to cast from a shared pointer to a shared pointer to constant object? `static_cast` also fails.

Comment: I think it is almost never a good idea to return a reference to a smart pointer. Either the caller needs a smart pointer in which case it is safer to return a smart pointer by value (see Bathsheba's answer) to avoid dangling references. Or the caller doesn't need a smart pointer in which case it is simpler to return a pointer or reference directly (see my answer).

Comment: Bad code and bad question. You cannot return a reference to a temporary. Please explain your constraints.

Comment: The correct term here is **conversion**, not **cast**. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler that you want it to do a conversion.

Answer (score 8):

Change your `get` to

```
std::shared_ptr<const int> get( )
```

which will remove what is essentially a dangling reference, and compilation will succeed.

Comment: That is true, but I need the same reference counted, just pointing to a constant type. With your solution, I am going to have two smart pointers in the end.

Comment: Well you're out of luck then. (Although I do invite folk to downvote this if I've simply given up through lack of ability!) You can't bind to a reference unless the types match exactly.

Comment: Either I misunderstand nyarlathotep108's comment or I missunderstand Bathsheba's answer. You do have two smart pointers in the end but they point to the same memory and share the same reference count, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 yes you get 2 pointers in the end. If you never have more than 1 pointer to the object, then there is absolutely no need for `shared_ptr`. That's the whole purpose of `shared_ptr` : having multiple pointers sharing ownership of a resource.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 have a look at [shared_ptr::shared_ptr (9)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 7):

If the caller of `A::get` only wants to observe `m_i` and doesn't want to obtain shared ownership then I would just return a pointer-to-const:

```
const int* get( ) { return m_i.get(); }
```

Holding a reference to a smart-pointer is no safer than a raw pointer. If the owner of the smart pointer goes out of scope you will have a dangling reference to a smart pointer.

Comment: alternative variation: `const int& get() { return *m_i; }`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed. Of course you have to be sure that `m_i` is not null.